# Equals gives TRUE comparing two different objects

Tags: .net, equals

I dont understand, why the following `equals` result is `true`. This example comes from msdn:

```
    Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder("abc")
    Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder("abc", 16)

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("a1) sb1.Length = {0}, sb1.Capacity = {1}", sb1.Length, sb1.Capacity)
    Console.WriteLine("a2) sb2.Length = {0}, sb2.Capacity = {1}", sb2.Length, sb2.Capacity)
    Console.WriteLine("a3) sb1.ToString() = ""{0}"", sb2.ToString() = ""{1}""", _
                           sb1.ToString(), sb2.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("a4) sb1 equals sb2: {0}", sb1.Equals(sb2))
```

When I check the msdn page for `equals` I find:

> Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared
>   refer to the same object.

So e.g.

```
Dim sb1 as New StringBuilder("abc")
Dim sb2 as Stringbuilder = sb1
sb1.equals(sb2)
```

In this example I would understand the result `true` but in the first example i have two different objects with two different references.

Could anyone explain to me why the result in the first example is `true`?

Comment: With a correctly (as intended) implemented `Equals` method, a `true` result means "you would not be able to tell the first object from the second no matter how hard you tried". That's a better definition to keep in mind. For many types of objects they would need to be the same instance to satisfy this condition, but for simpler things that is not necessary.

Comment: @Jon: That doesn't sound like a good implementation to me. You can always use `ReferenceEquals` to tell two distinct objects apart.

Comment: @JonSkeet: There's probably something you have in mind and I don't, but is there a BCL class that does not follow the above heuristic?

Comment: @Jon: Well *anything* that overrides `Equals` so that two distinct objects are equal. So `String` for example. You can tell two distinct but equal objects apart using `ReferenceEquals`, violating your requirement. Fundamentally I don't think it's a good idea to try to impose a one-size-fits-all meaning of `Equals`... the exact semantics will depend on the type. (Mutable types overriding Equals are awkward too, of course - `StringBuilder` being an example of that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: There's a misunderstanding here. "No matter how hard you tried" leaves "using the object's public interface" unsaid (perhaps it should not have). Obviously `ReferenceEquals` always does what it says on the tin, or you could compare unsafe pointers. Agree that mutable types overriding `Equals` is awkward.

Comment: @Jon: I like your definition of `Equals`, though unfortunately some types like `Double` and `Decimal` don't follow it [imho, `(1.0m).Equals(1.00m)` should return false, but doesn't].  Actually, there are two useful equivalence relations which could be meaningfully described among all objects.  Given references X and Y, the equivalence relations would be described by: (1) If a reference to X were overwritten with a reference to Y, would code using X's public interface notice? (2) If all references to X were replaced with references to Y, *and vice versa*, ...

Comment: ...would any code using X's public interface, *apart from the hash-code method for question 1*, notice?  There isn't any standard way for a class to answer the second question, but it's the proper question in many cases where an immutable object encapsulates its state in a privately-held reference to an object of a mutable type [the immutable class never mutates that object, and since nothing else has a reference to it, nothing else can mutate it either, so the *object* will be immutable even though its type isn't].  Note that the second question says nothing about immutability, but...

Comment: ...if a mutable type can answer the second question [whose answer would be well-defined for mutable and immutable classes alike], an immutable wrapper could use that answer when determining its answer to either equality-related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could anyone explain to me why the result in the first example is true?

Because [`StringBuilder` overloads `Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccth01t4.aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   true if this instance and sb have equal string, `Capacity`, and `MaxCapacity` values; otherwise, false.

As noted in comments:

- This is *not* overriding `Object.Equals(Object)` - if you change your code such that the compile-time types of `sb1` and `sb2` are `Object` rather than `StringBuilder` (or call the static `Object.Equals(Object, Object)` method), it will return `False`
- Your code relies on the default capacity of `StringBuilder` being 16 (for short initial strings); the equality check includes `Capacity` and `MaxCapacity`

Comment: This answer is not quite correct, but it would have been correct if the authors of `StringBuilder` had done what people normally do and should do. In fact, `StringBuilder` **does not** override `Object.Equals`. For example `Object.Equals(sb1, sb2)` returns `False`. The only thing `StringBuilder` class does is to introduce a new (unrelated) **overload** of `Equals`. This overload is not used by `EqualityComparer<StringBuilder>.Default` or anything else. But it can be called explicitly, of course, like in the question.

Comment: You should also mention that his example relied on the fact that `16` is the default capacity of a `StringBuilder`. Had he changed his instances to `New StringBuilder("abc")` and `New StringBuilder("abc", 14)`, for instance, they would differ because of different capacity. Crazy functionality, of course.